# Pause readable stream when piped to writable stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, node.js-stream

I have a readable stream that I would like to pause. It is piped to a writable stream. My code looks like this

```
const { get } = require('https');
const { createWriteStream };

const writableStream = createWriteStream(SOME_PATH);
get(SOME_URL, (res) => {
  res.pipe(writableStream);
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.pause();
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    res.resume();
  }, 4000);
});
```

This works well on Mac. But for some reason, on Windows while downloading from an `https` URL, this doesn't pause.

I think this is because my readable stream is piped to a writable stream and the writable stream is asking for more data, which resumes the stream. If I unpipe, this will solve the issue. Here is my code when I unpipe

```
const writableStream = createWriteStream(SOME_PATH);
get(SOME_URL, (res) => {
  res.pipe(writableStream);
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.unpipe(writableStream);
    res.pause();
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    res.pipe(writableStream);
    res.resume();
  }, 4000);
});
```

This actually causes my download to pause. But this creates a new issue. After calling `res.unpipe()`, I still get data events. This means that the few milliseconds in between calling `res.unpipe()` and `res.pause()`, some of my data is sent to the `res` pipe, but not written to `writableStream` pipe. This ends with my downloaded file getting corrupted.

Is there any way to fix this problem? I'm not married to the idea of unpiping, it's just the only solution I could come up with.

I was thinking about storing the data the `res` gets when not piped to `writableStream` and manually passing it to `writableStream` when they pipe again. Is that even possible? If not, are there other ways I can go about pausing a stream when piped to a readable stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure why this solution works, but it works for me. Instead of unpiping before I paused, I created a listener for `pause` and unpipe there. In addition, I also set `res.readableFlowing` to false manually. With these two additions, I was able to pause and resume without the download file breaking. Here's the implementation

```
let isPaused = false;
const writableStream = createWriteStream(SOME_PATH);
get(SOME_URL, (res) => {
  res.pipe(writableStream);
  setTimeout(() => {
    isPaused = true;
    res.pause();
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    isPaused = false;
    res.pipe(writableStream);
    res.resume();
  }, 4000);

  res.on('pause', () => {
    // Add this flag because pause event gets called many times, and we only
    // want this code to happen when we call it manually
    if (isPaused) {
      res.unPipe(writableStream);
      res.readableFlowing = false;
    }
  });
});
```